# Compare text string and through the exception if any of the condition not matched

Tags: c#

```
List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();

// Valid column names
columnNames.Add("IDRef"); 
columnNames.Add("RiskAssessmentTitle");
columnNames.Add("RiskAssessmentDate");
columnNames.Add("RiskAssessmentLabel");
columnNames.Add("Likelihood");
columnNames.Add("Impact");

// Anything with prefix DD - , MD - , DT - , RT - , FT - is valid column name
columnNames.Add("DD - IDRef"); 
columnNames.Add("MD - RiskAssessmentTitle");
columnNames.Add("DT - RiskAssessmentDate");
columnNames.Add("RT - RiskAssessmentLabel");
columnNames.Add("FT - Likelihood");
columnNames.Add("FT - Impact");


// Invalid column names

columnNames.Add("IDRefIDref");  // Invalid column names
columnNames.Add("RiskAssessmentTitle-title"); // Invalid column names
columnNames.Add("RiskAssessmentDate-title"); // Invalid column names
columnNames.Add("RiskAssessmentLabel-lable"); // Invalid column names
columnNames.Add("Likelihood-something"); // Invalid column names
columnNames.Add("Impact-impact-impact"); // Invalid column names


Need to do the validation to check the above condition

foreach(string columnName in columnNames){
    await ValidateColumns(columnName)
}

 async Task ValidateColumns(string columnName, int i)
{
    columnName.Trim();
    if (!columnName.EndsWith("IDRef") ||
        !columnName.EndsWith("RiskAssessmentTitle") ||
        !(columnName.EndsWith("RiskAssessmentDate")) ||
        !(columnName.EndsWith("RiskAssessmentLabel")) ||
        !(columnName.EndsWith("Likelihood")) ||
        !(columnName.EndsWith("Impact")))
        throw new KeyNotFoundException("ImportInvalidFieldRowNumber"));
}
```

The above function gets called on loop. So for all the above conditions it always throws a KeyNotFoundException, If there are valid columns as well. What is the best way to compare to pass and throw the exception?

Comment: At the end of your explanation, you say "_compare to pass and throw the exception?_" What does that mean? You cannot both pass and not pass (throw exception) at the same time (not considering quantum computing). Does that mean you want no exception if there are any valid column names?

Comment: Also, what's up with all the C# language tags? Are you limited to C# 4.0, or are you limited to C# 3.0, or are you limited to C# 2.0? Is it really the C# language version you are limited to or just a specific version of an old .NET Framework?

Comment: You should use `&&` to combine these conditions first.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace No I am not limited to that, I am using C# 10 with asp.net core

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Yes, I want to have no exception if the valid columns is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly this if statement is not a good idea, I will use 2 `HashSet`s if there are many prefixes and column names.

```
var prefixes = new HashSet<string>{ "DD", ... };
var columnNames = new HashSet<string>{ "IDRef", ... };

bool IsValidColumnName(string columnName)
{
    var p = columnName.IndexOf(" - ");
    if(p > 0)
       return prefixes.Contains(columnName.SubString(0, p)) &&       
           columnNames.Contains(columnName.SubString(p + 3));
    else
       return columnNames.Contains(columnName);
}
```